# How to exclude some databases in flyway db migration

Tags: java, mysql, flyway

I am using `flyway DB` for migrating databases. I have `multi tenant application`, in which there are many databases.

So my requirement is I want to execute `migration scripts` for some specific databases only and want to exclude other.

How can I achieve this in flyway DB? Please any one suggest solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found so far is to call migration in the code when you establish a new tenant connection. That's how you can skip calling flyway.migrate based on tenant name or soever.